# A User has read access to an Opportunity but is not in the OpportunityShare table - how come?

Tags: opportunity, sharing

My org *does not have* https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sharing_update_opportunity.htm&release=246&type=5 enabled yet (at least not that I'm aware!).

A User has read access to an opportunity but is NOT in the OpportunityShare table of that opportunity. I do see a corresponding record however, in the [UserRecordAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm) table.

I don't understand how this is possible, assuming that the aforementioned feature is not yet enabled? How can one have read access to an Opportunity but no corresponding row entry in the OpportunityShare table?

Comment: This turned out to be because a user had 'view all' on the Opportunity object via a permission set. Doing a SOQL check on ObjectPermissions was helpful too: SELECT Id, ParentId, SobjectType, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete, PermissionsViewAllRecords, PermissionsModifyAllRecords, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp FROM ObjectPermissions where PermissionsViewAllRecords = true